# How to access a substring using Batch programming? Also, how to manipulate a string to use it as integer value using batch programming?

Tags: string, batch-file

After I type

```
netsh wlan show interfaces
netsh wlan show interfaces > interface.txt
```

in my system's command prompt, I get the current connection profile. I am interested in seeking out the string part of '`Profile`' Section after the '`:`' part from the `interface.txt` file.

I'd prefer the program to go searching for 'Profile' using `findstr` and then extract the string part in the same line so that the code generated could be reused. How do I go about it?

Also, how do I use `string` data from a `text` file for manipulating it as an `integer` data?

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: what's the exact output of the command? As I have no wireless device on my machine I don't know what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%i in ('netsh wlan show interfaces^|find "  Profile"') do set p=%%j
echo %p: =%
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%i in ('netsh wlan show interfaces^|find "  Receive rate"') do set r=%%j
echo %r:~1%
```

**EDIT** npocmaka's comment reminded me, that some values (e.g. "Physical Address") contain colons. Edited code to get those values complete.

Note: the values have a starting space; With adding space to delimiters, this could be avoided, but on the other hand, some descriptions have more than one word ("Network Type"), so this is problematic. So I decided to let them in and "postprocess" the variable instead.

Comment: shouldn't the space also be included as delimiter?

Comment: in this special case, yes. But in general, it could be problematic, as "token 1" may consist of several words (eg. '  Network type   :').

Comment: I tried using your code as such. It says "Syntax incorrect". Any changes that I need to make?

Comment: sorry, transfer failure... Edited. Try again please.

Comment: A clarification, the value VOLSBB is being stored in p and the value of receive rate in r, is it?

Comment: profile stored to `p`, receive rate to `r`. Adapt the `find`string to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply split your string using `FOR` and `:` as delimeter. Say your sting is like

> SET yourstring = *something*: **somethingelse** *even more stuff* and you want to access **somethingelse**

Then you can use this:

```
REM this is to get everithing on the right of :
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%X IN ("%yourstring%") DO SET substring=%%X
REM this is to get the first token after the first white space
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%X IN ("%substring%") DO SET yourvalue=%%X
```

Now %yourvalue% will contain **somethingelse**.

To answer your second question:

If you want a string representing a number to be regarded as an integer you have to use `SET /A varname=%stringWithTheInteger%`. `/A` allows you to do arithmetic operations on variables.

Comment: If I am extracting the string from a text file, still the same 'SET /A' part?

Comment: Yes, always use /A if you want to treat a variable as an integer.